# Exception thrown writing to InputOutputArray

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to test some motion estimation in Visual Studio 2013, using OpenCV v3.0 (which is probably my 1st mistake!). I got an unhandled exception trying to use createOptFlow_DualTVL1() and createOptFlow_Farneback(), and then, for testing, tried cv::accumulate(), which threw the same exception.

It seems that OpenCV can't write to the Mat object that I'm passing these functions. I can't read the actual cvException because I don't have the PDB files, because I didn't compile this version myself. That might be my next stop, but before I do I figured I'd see if anyone's seen this behaviour before.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
    #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/video/tracking.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp>

    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <regex>

    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;

    int main(int argc, const char** argv)
    {
            VideoCapture captureDevice;
            std::string videoname = "example.mp4";
            captureDevice.open(videoname);

            //setup image files used in the capture process
            Mat currFrame, dst;

            captureDevice >> currFrame;
            accumulate(currFrame, dst, cv::noArray());

            imshow("outputCapture", dst);
            //pause for 33ms
            waitKey(33);

            return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`dst` should be of same size as that `currFrame` and of type `CV_32FC3`.
So, add this line of code before calling `accumulate` -

```
dst.create(currFrame.size(), CV_32FC3);
```

Since `dst` is of float type, you will need to convert it to uchar to display it. For that, convert as shown below -

```
Mat dst_disp;
dst.convertTo(dst_disp, CV_8UC3);
imshow("outputCapture",dst_disp );
```

Additionally, as you accumulate more frames in `dst`, you will need to normalize by number of frames(let's say `N`) cached in `dst`. Simply, divide `dst` by the `N`, then convert the result into `CV_8UC3` and display. For example, if you accumulated 1000 frames in `dst` do as shown below,

```
// Accumulate 1000 frames
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    accumulate(currFrame, dst, cv::noArray());
// Normalize 
dst = dst/ 1000;
// Display the frame
Mat dst_disp;
dst.convertTo(dst_disp, CV_8UC3);
imshow("outputCapture",dst_disp );
```

else, you might get an all white image.

**UPDATE**

***From @berak's comment below.***

For normalization, simply use

```
dst.convert(dst_disp, CV_8UC3, 1.0/N);
```

where `N` in example above will be 1000.

Comment: better even: dst = Mat(currFrame.size(), CV_32FC3,Scalar::all(0)); // since Mat.create does not initialize the memory

Comment: also: convert(dst_disp, CV_8UC3, 1.0/N); // would do it in one go.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement's @berak. I have updated the post to refer to your comments.

Comment: @bizk05 Ah, it seems my minimal working example was really sloppy! Thanks for fixing that. Anyway, I initialized dst as you suggested, and then converted it to uchar, but the exception is still thrown in the actual accumulate() call itself. It appears to be due to an inability to write to dst. I think I'll have to either compile OpenCV myself or try an older version to debug further.

Comment: @Stereoscopic Check the `currFrame` using something  like `if(!currFrame.data) return -1;`. The exception might be due to the `null` frame.

Comment: @bikz05 Just tried that there, currFrame has data. Also I'm now using opencv-2.4.10, and getting the same exception! I'm truly stumped at this stage... I'll probably try building the libs myself now, then I can use the pdb files to get some more insight.